# How to have replace my legend by an image in a map

Tags: python, pandas

So I have a problem here: I wan't to know how I can replace my legend which is now geographic coordinates by an image that is related to an url. (I've already searched on the net and asked ChatGPT to help me to do it, but both wasn't successful.)

This is my code so far:

```
fig = px.scatter_mapbox(Circuit, lat="lat", lon="lng", hover_name="name",
                        color_discrete_sequence=["red"], zoom=3, height=1000)
fig.update_traces(hovertemplate="<b>%{customdata[0]}</b><br><img src='%{customdata[1]}' width='200'>")
fig.update_traces(customdata=Circuit[['name', 'url']])
fig.update_layout(mapbox_style="open-street-map")
fig.update_layout(title_x=0.5,title_y=0.95,title_text='Cicruit dans le monde',margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})
fig.show()
```

Here are the [coordinates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPpYU.png) and  the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q08D2.png).

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the full [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and make yourself familiar with the formatting options.

Comment: there are undefined variables in the example code.
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)